# How to auto format the card number in inputbox?

Tags: abap, dynpro

In the second line below, can it give a space automatically after I type a 4-digit text e.g : `(XXXX space YYYY space ZZZZ)`?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do it dynamically when you typing the text.
But you can format the text in the `PAI` (once the person does an action, click on enter for example) with :  

`WRITE <yout_field> TO <your_field> USING EDIT MASK '____ ____ ____'.`

Comment: Not possible. SAP GUI/Dynpro is a very old technology which has been replaced with HTML/Javascript that you can embed in a Dynpro screen.